# Parse CSV File section wise

Tags: c#

I am new to in C# need help to write parser for below cvs file of data

```
[INFO]
LINE_NAME,MACHINE_SN,MACHINE_NAME,OPERATOR_ID
LineName,ParmiMachineSN,PARMI_AOI_1,engineer
[INFO_END]

[PANEL_INSP_RESULT]
MODEL_NAME,MODEL_CODE,PANEL_SIDE,INDEX,BARCODE,DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME,DEFECT_NAME,DEFECT_CODE,RESULT
E11-03356-0388-A-TOP CNG,,BOTTOM,47,MLT0388A03358CSNSOF1232210200052-0001,20201023,12:46:57,12:47:04,,,OK
[PANEL_INSP_RESULT_END]

[BOARD_INSP_RESULT]
BOARD_NO,BARCODE,DEFECT_NAME,DEFECT_CODE,BADMARK,RESULT
1,MLT0388A03358CSNSOF1232210200052-0001,,,NO,OK
2,MLT0388A03358CSNSOF1232210200052-0004,,,NO,OK
3,MLT0388A03358CSNSOF1232210200052-0003,,,NO,OK
4,MLT0388A03358CSNSOF1232210200052-0002,,,NO,OK
[BOARD_INSP_RESULT_END]

[COMPONENT_INSP_RESULT]
BOARD_NO,LOCATION_NAME,PIN_NUMBER,POS_X,POS_Y,DEFECT_NAME,DEFECT_CODE,RESULT
[COMPONENT_INSP_RESULT_END]
```

I need to parse the above file

Comment: can you share your file, it's easy

Comment: Just to be clear, this is *not* a CSV file. It's a file that contains CSV data, but interspersed with other data.

Comment: this csv file @KonradRudolph

Answer (score 0):

The following reads all text, creates an anonymous list with line index and line followed by looping through a list of sections. In the loop find a section and in this case displays to a console window.

```
internal partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        var items = (File.ReadAllLines("YourFileNameGoesHere")
            .Select((line, index) => new { Line = line, Index = index })
            .Select(lineData => lineData)).ToList();

        List<string> sections = new List<string>()
        {
            "INFO", 
            "PANEL_INSP_RESULT", 
            "BOARD_INSP_RESULT", 
            "COMPONENT_INSP_RESULT"
        };

        foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{section}");
            var startItem = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Line == $"[{section}]");
            var endItem = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Line == $"[{section}_END]");
            if (startItem is not null && endItem is not null)
            {
                bool header = false;
                for (int index = startItem.Index + 1; index < endItem.Index; index++)
                {
                    if (header == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\t{items[index].Line}");
                        header = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{items[index].Line}");
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tFailed to read this section");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can i show only ok lines data  int OKIndex = InputLine.IndexOf("OK"); full line of data

Comment: I have no code with `InputLine`, revise your current question to match my code. Also be more specific in regards to `OK`.